# Specic Websites think I'm in a completely different country

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet

I've noticed recently that some random websites think I'm in India instead of where I really am (The US.)

The website I notice it most is https://www.livesoccertv.com/, it seems to impact me on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.

I've tried clearing cookies to that website and nothing changes. Looking at my public IP address on https://whatismyipaddress.com/ it shows an address that comes up as being in the US.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Probably just an issue with the IP location API that the site uses.  There isn't really a fix, but informing the owner or support of the website is a good idea.